# Method chaining with pandas function

Tags: python, pandas

Why can't I chain the get_dummies() function?

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd
     .read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
     .drop(columns=['sepal_length'])
     .get_dummies()
)
```

This works fine:

```
df = (pd
     .read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
     .drop(columns=['sepal_length'])
)
df = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Comment: Please add the dataset / sample dataset that you are using.

Comment: Because `get_dummies` is a pandas function not a method for dataframe. In the first try, you're trying tp apply a function on a dataframe.

Comment: Is there anyway to chain the function?

Comment: @Nivel I don't think so!

Comment: you can actually chain it with `pd.Series.str.get_dummies()` which is a series method. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) can be helpful in chaining methods or function calls which are not natively attached to the DataFrame, like `pd.get_dummies`:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['sepal_length']).pipe(pd.get_dummies)
```

Or with `lambda`:

```
df = (
    df.drop(columns=['sepal_length'])
        .pipe(lambda current_df: pd.get_dummies(current_df))
)
```

---

Sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': 1, 'a': list('ABACC'), 'b': list('ACCAB')})
```

`df`:

```
   sepal_length  a  b
0             1  A  A
1             1  B  C
2             1  A  C
3             1  C  A
4             1  C  B
```

Sample Output:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['sepal_length']).pipe(pd.get_dummies)
```

`df`:

```
   a_A  a_B  a_C  b_A  b_B  b_C
0    1    0    0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0    0    0    1
2    1    0    0    0    0    1
3    0    0    1    1    0    0
4    0    0    1    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain the `pd.get_dummies()` method since it is not a `pd.DataFrame` method. However, assuming -

1. You have a **single column** left after you drop your columns in the previous step in the chain.
2. Your column is a **string column dtype**.

... you can use `pd.Series.str.get_dummies()` which is a [series level method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies).

```
### Dummy Dataframe
#       A  B
#    0  1  x
#    1  2  y
#    2  3  z

pd.read_csv(path).drop(columns=['A'])['B'].str.get_dummies()
```

```
   x  y  z
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

> NOTE: Make sure that before you call the get_dummies() method, the data type of the object is series. In this case, I fetch column `['B']` to do that, which kinda makes the previous `pd.DataFrame.drop()` method unnecessary and useless :)
>
> But this is only for example's sake.